# Will SOLR perform matching on the street name?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I have a query regarding matching a street name in SOLR.

The actual street name to match is POTTS ROAD EVANSFIELD VIC. I have stored the data in three fields:

```
street_name_clean : POTTSROADEVANSFIELDVIC
street_name_space : POTTS ROAD EVANSFIELD VIC
street_name : POTTS, ROAD, EVANSFIELD, VIC
```

The reason for storing the data as such is so that I can perform an exact search, fuzzy search, ngram search, proxmity matching etc.

I have see a case where the user inputs POTTROAD (missing S from the actual street name) and all my searches fail.

Is there a technique to match POTTROAD with the data above? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A stemmer (or a possesive filter or a patter replace filter that removes s-es at the end of words) + a ShingleFilter possibly? The stemmer will remove the S, while a ShingleFilter will combine multiple tokens to a single one - giving you `POTT`, `POTTROAD`, `POTTROADEVANSFIELD`, etc. Do you have any other examples of matches failing based on what the user is typing? The ShingleFilter combined with a fuzzy search would probably also work; `POTTROAD~1` should give a hit if you've indexed `POTTSROAD`.

Comment: ShingleFilter looks like a good option. Even if the token generated are POTTS, POTTSROAD, POTTSROADEVANSFIELD etc. (not removing the s'es at the end), combining it with fuzzy search might do the trick.

The question now is how to implement the ShingleFilter to generate tokens as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @MatsLindh, I implemented the ShingleFilter as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_shingle" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\s+)" replacement="" replace="all" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```